# How to use 2FA with cert based SSH auth?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I used [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/) to enable Google TOTP auth on Ubuntu 16.04.

SSH only allows cert based auth (`PasswordAuthentication no`)

I set `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes` and restarted the SSH service.

I don't get prompted for a 2FA token.

So I added the following line to sshd_config:

`AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive`

Then restarted the SSHd

Now I get prompted for a password after entering the cert password, but the 2FA codes are not accepted. I used both the main numeric keyboard and the dedicated numeric keyboard to enter the numbers.

`UsePAM yes` hasn't been changed.

**How to config 2FA with cert based SSH auth?**